# Drag and drop when droppable is rotated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation

I'm using jQuery UI drag and drop. My droppables are rotated, and I have problem, because wrong droppable gets drop event. Any solution for good behaviour, when droppable is rotated?

Comment: it is better if you could provide a demo on jsfiddle.net for easy understanding and solving